# Buttons to fill width of container

Tags: html, css, button

I have the following code for a CSS button group:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxunuqf5/

Basically, my goal is to have the `.button-group` be 100% of the .container, with the buttons evenly spaced.

I tried adding:

```
.button-group .button {
    width: 33.3%; /* There is three buttons, so 100/3% */
}
```

but it leaves a gap (not 100% width) at the very end?

Comment: Like this? ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxunuqf5/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle does not have the css you tried to add

Comment: @chipChocolate.py, why does it have a gap though at the end?

Comment: @infinity - http://jsfiddle.net/Lxunuqf5/2/

Comment: Your button group is display inline block so the width is not 100% of its container which leads to adding the width not working as you expected it to. Your buttons are also floating so if you do change button group to display block the buttons still won't take the width since it's floating. Multiple issues

Comment: Part of the issue is that you're trying to set the width and set the padding, but they are both trying to affect the same thing, so pick one.

Comment: @slime, the reason I do this is so I can have just a single button (which should have padding), and then also have button group buttons (which have a set width). Should I just change to have two classes for .button?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py, that works, thanks, can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apply `position: relative` to `.button-group`.
2. Remove `margin-left: -1px` from `.button` and the following:

   ```
   .button + .button,
   .button + .button-group,
   .button-group + .button,
   .button-group + .button-group {
       margin-left: 15px;
   }
   ```
3. Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` in `.button`.
4. Remove the *white-space* between the `a` tags in your markup.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxunuqf5/2/)**

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  background: yellow;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: .01rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid darken($GRAY, 10%);
  font-size: em(13);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: teal;
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.button-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* IE hacks */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.button-group li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.button-group .button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.button-group > .button:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
.button-group li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .button {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.button-group > .button:first-child,
.button-group li:first-child .button {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.button-group > .button:last-child,
.button-group li:last-child > .button {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='button-group'>
    <a class='button'>Test Uno</a
    ><a class='button'>Test Dos</a
    ><a class='button'>Test Tres</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't distribute the buttons evenly if you use `float`.

Instead, you can use flexbox:

```css
.button-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  background: yellow;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: .01rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid darken($GRAY, 10%);
  font-size: em(13);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: teal;
}
.button-group {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* IE hacks */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.button + .button,
.button + .button-group,
.button-group + .button,
.button-group + .button-group {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.button-group li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.button-group > .button:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
.button-group li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .button {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.button-group > .button:first-child,
.button-group li:first-child .button {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.button-group > .button:last-child,
.button-group li:last-child > .button {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.button-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='button-group'>
    <a class='button'>Test Uno</a>
    <a class='button'>Test Dos</a>
    <a class='button'>Test Tres</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be sure to check browser compatibility before implementing. Basically, if you need to support older browsers, don't use this